# ninja_syntax missing when trying to build chromium arc

Tags: android, build, chromium

I am trying to build arc on ubuntu 14.04 but I get the following error:

```
➜  arc git:(master) ✗ ./configure 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "src/build/configure.py", line 17, in <module>
    import config_loader
  File "/home/ligi/git/3rd/arc/src/build/config_loader.py", line 125, in <module>
    load_from(paths)
  File "/home/ligi/git/3rd/arc/src/build/config_loader.py", line 96, in load_from
    config_module = imp.load_source(module_name, path_name, config_file)
  File "/home/ligi/git/3rd/arc/mods/android/bionic/config.py", line 13, in <module>
    import make_to_ninja
  File "/home/ligi/git/3rd/arc/src/build/make_to_ninja.py", line 19, in <module>
    import ninja_generator
  File "/home/ligi/git/3rd/arc/src/build/ninja_generator.py", line 34, in <module>
    import ninja_syntax
ImportError: No module named ninja_syntax
```

I was runing the install-build-deps script as suggested in the README:

```
➜  arc git:(master) ✗ ./src/build/install-build-deps.sh  # Ubuntu 14.04
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
g++-arm-linux-gnueabihf is already the newest version.
gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf is already the newest version.
libcap-dev is already the newest version.
libtinfo5 is already the newest version.
python-markdown is already the newest version.
pbzip2 is already the newest version.
pigz is already the newest version.
libasound2:i386 is already the newest version.
libcairo2:i386 is already the newest version.
libcap2:i386 is already the newest version.
libgconf-2-4:i386 is already the newest version.
libglib2.0-0:i386 is already the newest version.
libncurses5:i386 is already the newest version.
libpango1.0-0:i386 is already the newest version.
libtinfo5:i386 is already the newest version.
libxcomposite1:i386 is already the newest version.
libxcursor1:i386 is already the newest version.
libxdamage1:i386 is already the newest version.
libxi6:i386 is already the newest version.
libxinerama1:i386 is already the newest version.
libxrandr2:i386 is already the newest version.
libxss1:i386 is already the newest version.
libxtst6:i386 is already the newest version.
libc6-dev-i386 is already the newest version.
libosmesa6 is already the newest version.
openjdk-6-jdk is already the newest version.
libcups2:i386 is already the newest version.
libfontconfig1:i386 is already the newest version.
libgl1-mesa-dev:i386 is already the newest version.
libgtk2.0-0:i386 is already the newest version.
libnss3:i386 is already the newest version.
libosmesa6:i386 is already the newest version.
libudev1:i386 is already the newest version.
linux-libc-dev:i386 is already the newest version.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-3.13.0-24 linux-headers-3.13.0-24-generic
  linux-image-3.13.0-24-generic linux-image-extra-3.13.0-24-generic
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 12 not upgraded.
```

also depot_tools are in my path:

```
➜  3rd  ninja
ninja: error: loading 'build.ninja': No such file or directory
➜  3rd  which ninja
/home/ligi/git/3rd/depot_tools/ninja
```

I am stuck here - and google has no hit for "ImportError: No module named ninja_syntax" ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue just trying to run the `launch_chrome.py` script and noticed the scripts were all assuming `third-party/tools/ninja` to have something in it. Given it was empty I concluded that must be a git submodule, so a simply `git clone` wouldn't have pulled those sources in.

If you already got a working directory, you may initialize/update its submodules by executing (on the root of your working copy):

`git submodule update --init --recursive`

That should pull everything in. You also have the option to clone the repo already pulling all of its submodules with it by executing `git clone --recursive https://chromium.googlesource.com/arc/arc`.